# PDF to base64 converter and viewing base64

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, pdf, base64

I am getting a PDF file via JSON and this file is coming in base64 in a string. I wanted to test this base64 to see if it mounts the PDF correctly. How could he do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it by throwing it in HTML file.  I had the exact same requirement and this was the easiest method I found ...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <embed style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="data:application/pdf;base64,YOUR_BASE64_STRING_GOES_HERE" type="application/pdf"></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got you friend. Thank you very much.

I made a test by inserting into the browser url bar only: **data:application/pdf;base64, YOUR_BASE64_STRING_GOES_HERE** and I was able to get the same result as well, so we do not need to create an HTML file and run.

Comment: Beautiful ...! Thanks for the tip, didn’t know that.